# API which returns IAsyncEnumerable<T> but results are not streamed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, async-await

I am trying consume API which returns IAsyncEnumerable

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Xtype> Get([Required]int maxx=10)
{
    var result = _context.dbcontext.Take(maxx).AsAsyncEnumerable();

    await foreach (var Xtype in y)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); 
        yield return Xtype;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting results after 10 seconds but I thought I would start getting results after each second

Comment: What is XType and y here?! please edit your question, it's completely unclear and also correct its formatting issues.

Comment: HTTP doesn't allow streaming results. Returning an `IAsyncEnumerable` doesn't mean the service will return individual HTTP responses for each item - there's no such thing. You need to use SignalR or gRPC with server streaming if you want to return a stream of data to the server.

Comment: XType is some return type i am returning

Comment: When you return an `IAsyncEnumerable`, an HTTP service in **any** stack or language will still return one response, writing each item to the response stream as it arrives. The difference with `IEnumerable` is that the middleware doesn't have to block waiting for each item to be produced

Comment: i mean on client side i am calling like this var stringTask = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://localhost/api/?maxx=10");    so it takes 10 seconds to hit  this line of code   var reslt = Deserialize<IEnumerable<Xtype>>(stringTask); so i assuming  this is same as ienumerable

Comment: It's really the same over network! In short async/await only have benefits in its process domain. not over network

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 instances when this occurs; one is in ASP.NET Core 3 & 5, where the default behaviour is for MVC to buffer `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` types before sending it to the serializer. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/iasyncenumerable-not-buffered-by-mvc

The other case is in .NET 6, when hosted under IIS (and also IIS Express). By default, IIS will buffer response bodies, but it can be disabled programmatically in C#:

`HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>()?.DisableBuffering();`

Add the above statement in the body of your controller method (before the `foreach` loop that has the `yield return` statement). I tested the above in a .NET 6 project and it worked to disable the buffering under IIS Express and IIS 10.